# Get meta data from delegated files using QML

Tags: file, qt, metadata, qml

I'm creating a music player for Ubuntu Touch in QML and I have some things I would appreciate some help with since I'm new to QML.

I have a list of tracks from a directory, but I want to show the meta data (artist, track name, year, album and so on) instead of the filename.

Using Qt.Multimedia am able to get the meta data from the currently playing track, but I can't find how to do it per file from my FolderListModel delegated files.

How would I do that?

This is the current code:

```
            Column {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                anchors.fill: parent
                ListView {
                    id: musicFolder
                    FolderListModel {
                        id: folderModel
                        folder: musicDir
                        showDirs: false
                        nameFilters: ["*.ogg","*.mp3","*.oga","*.wav"]
                    }
                    width: parent.width
                    height: parent.height
                    model: folderModel
                    delegate: ListItem.Subtitled {
                        text: fileName
                        subText: "Artist: "
                        onClicked: {
                            console.debug('Debug: User pressed '+musicDir+fileName)
                            playMusic.source = musicDir+fileName
                            playMusic.play()
                            trackInfo.text = playMusic.metaData.albumArtist+" - "+playMusic.metaData.title // show track meta data
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I am not sure about QtMultimedia, but in Phonon, you had to actually play the file first, before you could extract the meta data. To extract the data explicitly from all the files in the folder, you would have to use external libraries like http://taglib.github.io/ Is the behavior same in QtMultimedia as well ?

Comment: Hi again Amit, well, yes it seems like I do have to play each track first, before extracting the meta data using QtMultimedia. But it uses quite a lot of power and made the app really slow, that's why I wanted to see if there were any other choices that could be made instead of that way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the easiest thing to do here would be to go get a C++ library that can parse the meta data out of these files and use it to create a custom ListModel in C++ that populates this information onto itself.  Unfortunately, this will have to be done in C++ as javascript does not have the IO capabilities to read and parse files.

Comment: Thanks. If that will be the case, I hope some of the becoming contributors the the music app will help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think I might go ahead and use QtMultimedia, but keep data in a local database. On startup, it checks the music dir and adds/removes tracks. That way it will be only be slow at first startup (hopefully)